# Magento - Add Shipping Postcode to Order Grid

Tags: magento

How would I go about getting the customers shipping postcode to be displayed in a column in the order grid?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Magento are you working on?

Comment: Why don't you accept an answer. `Celldweller`'s answer is working.

Answer (score 2):

Create yourself a custom module and overwrite `<sales_order_grid>`

In your Grid.php you need to do 2 different things:

1. Tell Magento where to find the postcode
2. Tell Magento where to put it

The best way to tell Magento where to find the info is the setCollection function. This function is called from within _prepareCollection so you don't have to mess that function up.

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    parent::setCollection($collection);
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(
            array('address' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),
            'main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "shipping"',
            array('postcode')
        );
}
```

Here you did a join and defined that the info can be found with the alias 'postcode'

Now all that is left is to tell Magento where to put it. Just override the _prepareColumn function:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();

    $this->addColumn('postcode',
        array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Postcode'),
            'index'     => 'postcode'
        )
    );

    return $this;
}
```

index refers to the name you set in the setCollection function.
If you want to put the column to a specific place, you should use addColumnAfter()

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In your model Grid,

in _prepareColumns() function make sure

```
    $this->setData('column_filters',array('shippingpostcode' => 'mymodule/sales_order_filter_shippingpostcode'));
    $this->addColumn('shippingpostcode', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Postcode'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'shipping_postcode', //you would need this field in your order table
        'renderer' => 'mymodule/sales_order_renderer_shippingpostcode',
    ));
```

and create a class

```
Mymodule_Model_Sales_Order_Render_Shippingpostcode extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Abstract
```

and in the function getHtml you can return whatever value you want to render on Grid.

Comment: OP is asking about adding to existing grid, not creating a new grid. This answer does not address this requirement in the least.

Comment: If you want to add a column in sales order grid you would obviously override the Grid.php and override the function _prepareColumns() and simply add a column by doing the above. It is a very simple solution. I think you didn't understand my code.

Comment: No, your solution suggested creating an entirely new grid block. Your comment indicates that you intend for the OP to extend from the original sales order grid block.